# javascript function to calculate difference in two dates, return short format, rounding to single unit

Tags: javascript, function, math, datetime, datediff

I struggled with wording the title, but basically I want a function where I can provide two dates and it would output something like: "2w" if the result was 15 days or "1y" if it was 13 months or "1m" if it was 4 or 5 weeks.  Preferably down to the hour... but 1 day minimum.

I found a similar SO question but it's for PHP and isn't complete anyway: [How to calculate the difference between two days as a formatted string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993067/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-days-as-a-formatted-string)

Comment: Can you show us your code so far? This is pretty straight forward stuff, you've even got a code sample there.

Comment: Like you said, it's pretty straightforward but very meticulous.  Given that, I was hoping such a function already existed and I wouldn't have to reinvent the wheel...  It's a minor cosmetic convenience that I can't afford to spend time on.  If I can't find an existing one I'll just display the "last updated" date instead of "updated 4 months ago".

Comment: And @RobertRozas, that blog post is pretty awesome.  I still feel like this circumstance is a bit different though and it's a time-consuming function that likely already exists.  Maybe not.

Comment: This JSfiddle is very close.  I may be able to modify it easily: http://jsfiddle.net/x9paT/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of javascript date libraries out there that will do all you want and more. Here is an example using [XDate](http://arshaw.com/xdate/)

```
<div id="result"><div/>

var now = new XDate();

var then = new XDate(2013, 04, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0);

document.getElementById("result").textContent = now.diffWeeks(then).toFixed(1) + " Weeks";
```

Available of [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/WtAQB/)

Here is with [Moments.js](http://momentjs.com/)

```
<div id="result"><div/>

var then = moment("Dec 25, 1995");

document.getElementById("result").textContent = moment(then, "YYYYMMDD").fromNow();
```

also vailable on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/yaVZP/)

Comment: When I changed the "then" date year to 2012 it resulted in a negative number.  Also, this excludes all the logic for rounding to the nearest unit (y,m,w,d,h)

Comment: As I said there are other libraries available, also including Moments.js(http://momentjs.com/) and Datejs(https://code.google.com/p/datejs/) are 2 more, I'm sure one of them does exactly what he wants, whatever exactly that is.